# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Good morning,
I am using tkinter with matplotlib but I am facing a problem which I will write down.

I tried many solution but nothing worked, so if you had faced the problem before or if you just know it help me please with it.
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')
middle = Frame(root)
middle.pack()

payments = {'.':0}
m = datetime.datetime.now()


def digram1():
    global m

    purpose = list(payments.keys())
    amounts = list(payments.values())  
    plt.plot((purpose),(amounts))
    plt.xlabel('Purpose')
    plt.ylabel('Amounts')
    plt.title('Outgoings for the '+ str(m.month)+'th month\n'+str(datetime.date.today()))
    plt.show


    fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi = 100)
    ex = fig.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ex,master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side =tk.top,fill=tk.Both, expand = True)


digram1m = Button(middle,text='1st digram',command=digram1, height = 5,width =15 , fg ='green')
digram1m.grid(row = 5 , column = 6 ,sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

and here is the output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-6c5b0c8eaae5>", line 33, in digram1
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ex,master=root)
  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 173, in __init__
    FigureCanvasAgg.__init__(self, figure)
  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1780, in __init__
    figure.set_canvas(self)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'
```

I am using Jupyter notebook 5.4.0.
Thank you for your time..

Comment: it should be `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=root)`.

Comment: More generally, you probably do not want to mix pyplot (`plt`) with your custom tkinter GUI. To avoid this, don't import pyplot at all, which makes it more natural to plot to the axes you create within the figure you later use in the tk app.

Comment: but I need some graphs to appear in the program, that's why imported pyplot..

Comment: Maybe I'm interpreting the code in the wrong way. Is the indentation correct? What exactly should the program do?

Comment: It is supposed to show me the digram1 function which should show a digram using matplotlib.

Comment: That's clear. But should it show the figure inside your Tk app or inside a new window?

Comment: inside the same Tk,

Comment: That's what I thought. If you look at the [example about embedding in tk](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) it also doesn't import pyplot. Instead you would want to directly plot to an axes, in your case e.g. `ex.plot(...)`, `ex.set_xlabel(...)` etc.